# Problem accessing the json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I am using jquery 1.5. I am using getJSON method to get the json output..

```
  $.getJSON('/products/list/', function(data) { ..... });
```

The json is structured like..

```
{"books":["title_of_books1","title_of_books2","title_of_books3"],
 "discs":["title_of_discs1","title_of_discs2"],
  etc....,
}
```

Is there a way to convert this into an array using jquery. So I can access it like `books[0]`

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your JSON syntax is correct, the data would be automatically converted to a native object by jQuery, so inside `function (data) { ..... }`, you would refer to `data.books[0]`:

```
$.getJSON('/products/list/', function(data) { 
    alert(data.books[0]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks It works great. One last thing, is there any way I can convert data.books to array using jquery.

Comment: @Ivanka: I'm not sure what you mean by that - `data.books` is already an array.

Answer (score 0):

use the parseJSON api of jquery.. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: That isn't necessary with `$.getJSON`, because `parseJSON` is implied.

Comment: @Andy E You are right, read the doc again, it says "The success callback is passed the returned data,...... JSON structure and parsed using the $.parseJSON() method. ...". So parseJSON will not be needed here..! :)